# Quiz programme for GCSE

Tags: python, homework, quiz

I made a quiz programme for my GCSE Computer Science NEA. I just want to make sure it is OK to submit.

There are also 5 files:
Usernames,
Passwords,
Song Names,
Artist Names and
High Scores.

Any feedback is appreciated, positive or negative!

```
import random # Imports the random module
def readData(): # Load Files and Log In
    with open("Song Names.txt", "r") as f:# Opens the song file
        songNames = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]# Puts the song file into a list
        f.close()
    with open("Artist Names.txt", "r") as f:# Opens the artists file
        artistNames = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]# Puts the artists file into a list
        f.close()
    with open("Usernames.txt", "r") as f:# Opens the username file
        usernames = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]# Puts the username file into a list
        f.close()
    with open("Passwords.txt", "r") as f:# Opens the username file
        passwords = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]# Puts the username file into a list
        f.close()
    return songNames, artistNames, usernames, passwords # Returns the newly created list

def login(usernames, passwords):
    global enterUsername
    enterUsername = input("Enter username\n> ")# Prompts the user to enter their username
    if enterUsername in usernames: # If the username is in usernames...
        enterPassword = str(input("Enter password\n> ")) # Prompts the user to enter their password
        usernamePos = usernames.index(enterUsername) # Finds the position ofthe username
        if enterPassword in passwords: # If the password is in passwords...
            passwordPos = passwords.index(enterPassword) # Finds the position of the entered password
            if usernamePos == passwordPos: # If the password and the username is in the same position
                print ("You are logged in", enterUsername) # Log in!
                return True
            else: # If the password is not in the same position
                print("You entered the wrong password...") # Inform the user about their mistake
        else: # If the password is not in passwords...
            print("That password is not in the file...")# Inform the user about their mistake
    else: # If the username is not in usernames
        print("You're not allowed to play the game...") # Inform the user about their mistake
    return False # Tell the programme that the user did not log in

def chooseSong(songNames, artistNames): # Sets up the song requirew
    secretSong = random.choice(songNames) # Generates a random song
    sSP = songNames.index(secretSong) # Finds the position of the secret song
    secretArtist = artistNames[sSP] # Gets the correct artist from the song
    return secretSong, secretArtist # Returns the song or artist

def loadGame(secretSong, secretArtist): # Loads the game
    word_guessed = [] # return secretSong
    print ("The artist is ", secretArtist, "and the song is", secretSong) # Print the artists nam
    for letter in secretSong: # Prints the song name (censored, of course)
        if letter == " ": # If the ltetter is a space...
            word_guessed.append(" / ")  # Print a dash       
        else: # Otherwise...
            word_guessed.append("-") # Print a line
    for letter in word_guessed: 
        print (letter, end = " ")
    return secretSong # Returns the secret song

def playGame(secretSong, score): # Plays the game
    tries = 0 # Sets the amount of tries to 0
    while True:
        userGuess = str(input("\nWhat is the song name?\n> ")) # Gives the user the oppertunity to guess the song name
        if userGuess == secretSong: # If the user guesses correctly...
            print("Correct!") # Prints that they are correct
            if tries == 0: # If they got the song name correct on their first try
                score = score + 3 # Add 3 points to thesongNames = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f] score
                print("You earnt 3 points! You have", score, "points in total.") # States that the user has got 3 points, and states the amount of points the user has in total
                time.sleep(1) # Wait a second
                return score, True # Return the score and True, to run the game again 
            elif tries == 1: # If they got the song name correct on their second try
                score = score + 1 # Add 1 point to the score
                print("You earnt 1 point! You have", score, "points in total.") # States that the user has got 1 point, and states the amount of points the user has in total
                time.sleep(1) # Wait a second
                return score, True # Return the score and True, to run the game again 
        else: # If the user guessed the song wrong
            tries = tries + 1 # You add a try to the programme
            if tries == 2: # while the tries are equal to 2
                print ("Game over! You got", score, "points!") # Prints the game over screen, showing the points they earned in the game (if any)
                time.sleep(3) # Waits three seconds
                return score, False # Returns False, to display the high scores
                break # Breaks from the while True loop
                print("You have 1 try left.") # Prints that the user has 1 try left
            else:
                print("Incorrect!") # Tells the user that they were wrong
                time.sleep(0.5) # Wait half a second 
                print("You have 1 try left.") # Prints that the user has 1 try left
def highScore(score, enterUsername):
    sTF1 = (enterUsername + " scored ") # Save To File part 1
    sTF2 = (str(score + " points.")) # Save To File part 2
    sTF = str("\n" + sTF1 + sTF2) # Save To File
    with open("Scores.txt", "r") as f: # Opens the score file
        highScores = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
        f.close()# Writes the score to the high score file
    with open("Scores.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(sTF)
        f.close()
    openScores = input("Would you like to see the score? Y/N\n> ")  # Gives the user the option to view the scores
    if openScores.lower() == ("y" or "yes"):
        print (highScores)
        time.sleep(5)
        quit()
    else:
        quit()

def main():
    songNames, artistNames, usernames, passwords = readData()# Reads the data from text files
    score = 0 # Set the score to 0
    success = login(usernames, passwords)# prompts the user to login
    if success == True: # If they log in successfully
        while True: 
            print ('''Rules of the game!
1) The name of the song is in all capitals
2) There must be no space after your entry
3) Have fun!''')
            secretSong, artist = chooseSong(songNames, artistNames) # Chooses a random song
            loadGame(secretSong, artist) # Creates the censored song name
            score, win = playGame(secretSong, score) # Plays the game
            if win == False: # If you lose the game
                highScore(score, enterUsername)
                break
main() #Plays the game!
```

Comment: As this is for an assignment, don't forget that when you submit it, you must acknowledge any help received.

Comment: To clarify Toby's point: not doing so would be academic misconduct in many schools and universities. People have got failing marks or dismissals for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few general comments first:

- Python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It recommends using `lower_case` for both functions and variables. It also recommends no space between `print` and `(`.
- Don't write obvious comments like this (unless your class requires each line to be commented, in that case realize that that is a stupid requirement and the reason it is stupid is that you end up writing comments like this):

  ```
  if enterUsername in usernames: # If the username is in usernames...
  if letter == " ": # If the ltetter is a space...
  else: # Otherwise...
  ```

Now, to get to the more salient points. You are doing this pattern quite often:

1. Find the index of an element / choose a random element from list 1
2. Find the matching element in list 2.

This is both slow (`list.index` is \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$) and can easily produce wrong results. Consider e.g. this example:

```
song_names = ["The Man Who Sold The World", "The Man Who Sold The World"]
artist_names = ["David Bowie", "Nirvana"]
```

If you randomly choose the second song, you will still always get the first artist, since `list.index` always returns the first match.

Instead either make your data a list of tuples of song titles and artists:

```
def random_song(song_names, artist_names)
    songs = list(zip(song_names, artist_names))
    return random.choice(songs)
```

Or choose a random index in the first place:

```
def random_song(song_names, artist_names)
    i = random.randrange(len(song_names))
    return song_names[i], artist_names[i]
```

Instead of iterating over `word_guessed`, just `str.join` the list:

```
def load_game(secret_song, secret_artist):
    """Starts a new game with the given secrets."""
    print ("The artist is {secret_artist} and the song is {secret_song}")
    word_guessed = [" / " if letter == " " else "-" for letter in secret_song]
    print(" ".join(word_guessed))
    return secret_song
```

Here I also used the new [`f-string`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (Python 3.6+) and a [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) with a [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator) used inside.

You should put the call to `main` under a [`if __name__ == "__main__":`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) guard to allow importing from this script from another script.

Answer (score 4):

When you are using `with` statement call to `close` is redundant. Once the flow comes out of `with` expression, closing the file is taken care. Check out the [pep](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html) for more details on this.

[Avoid global variables](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/pyguide.md#25-global-variables)

We are first reviewing if the username is in our list and then trying to get its index. A quick way to do it would be to use exception handling,

```
try:
    usernamePos = usernames.index(username)
except ValueError:
    # username is not in the list
    print("you are not allowed.")
```

Use doc strings to document the functions, than adding comment to the right side of the function definition. for eg.

```
def readData():
    """Load Files and Log In."""
```

Tricky use of `openScores.lower() == ("y" or "yes")`. Try `'y' or 'yes'` in python interpreter to understand this.

When dealing with `boolean` it is replication to specify it in the statement. it is sufficient to say `if success` as it is already an evaluated boolean.